# tokenizing error in pandas read_csv, can read a csv I download, but not directly from url

Tags: pandas, csv

I can download the data at https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/Institution/TopHoldingExportToCSV

And then I can read the data with pandas using

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:someplace\LargeHoldingCompanies.csv")
```

But I would like to read it directly as

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/Institution/TopHoldingExportToCSV')
```

This results is a long error.  I saw elsewhere that I could use  error_bad_lines=False, but that does not work either. (Different error)

What am I missing?

Extra information:
When I type the URL https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/Institution/TopHoldingExportToCSV
the file is automatically downloaded to my download directory.  However, when I use a wget('https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/Institution/TopHoldingExportToCSV', 'TopHoldings.csv')
The contents are not the csv, but html.

Comment: The linkt does not work

Comment: @Erfan I added some extra information.  I realize that the link doesn't put anything in the browser; however, copy-pasting that link to the browser window does download the csv file. (Or, it does for me)

Comment: Still does not work, also when you want to load the data directly in a dataframe, you need the raw data, not a downloadlink.

Comment: @erfan that's helpful.  I need to read a few things and maybe ask a different question.

Comment: [This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv) is what I mean with "raw"

Comment: I don't see any such link to raw data.  I think I need some way other than pandas or wget (which I've also tried) to capture it.